# Migraring from NTLM to Kerberos

Tags: spring, security, kerberos, ntlm

I have an application that is using spring security and NTLM for single sign on. It also uses active directory to get the user groups. It has a 
springSecurityFilterChain configured where one of the filter is NTLMFilter.
The NTLM filter (org.springframework.security.ui.ntlm.NtlmProcessin gFilter) is configured with , AD domain, controller, and jcifs properties etc.
I need to move the NTLM part to kerberos, keeping rest of the process same.
I was hoping I can replace the ntmlFilter to some kerberos filer but don’t find any such documentation details or examples.
Any help or direction to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much

Comment: Check http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-kerberos/